# Get single item from a collection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm new to AngularJS and need to consume a REST API. I can successfully load the collection of projects from the server using two different ways, but I fail to get a single project from this list (after it's been populated) by its id. I do not want to get the item again from the server.

When I try with `angularjs-rails-resource`, I can get the list of items using `Project.query()`and store it in `$rootScope.projects`. However I now wonder how to get an item out of this list by its id (actually it's not an array but a promise)?

I also tried with `restangular` using `$rootScope.projects = Restangular.all("projects").getList()` and `project = $rootScope.projects.get(id)`. But this also fails, because it seems to return a collection and not a single item...?!

Answer (score 0):

For `angularjs-rails-resource` you should be able to just use `get(id)`. It will always return a promise which is fine if you're using it in your template because templates understand promises.

If you don't want a promise, you can use `then`

```
Project.get(1234).then(function (project) {
    //project is NOT a promise
    $scope.project = project;
});
```

rather than

```
//project is a promise, but you're template is cool with that
$scope.project = Project.get(1234);
```

Comment: But this does another call to the server. I want to get the item from the preloaded list I stored in $rootScope.projects.

Comment: I misunderstood, probably you can just loop through them using forEach... add a method to your factory.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how to do this. Can you give me a full example, enhancing the Basic Example from the angularjs-rails-resource website?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md under 'adding custom methods'. But I really think you should reconsider your approach. If you only rely on the list you got initially you run a higher risk of your data going stale.... why not just do another request? Isn't that kind of the point of REST?

Answer (score 0):

In order to return single item use:

```
$scope.project = Project.get(id: some_id);
```